# Add more fields function and populate second combobox based on first combobox can be run for all row insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, combobox

I have jQuery PHP function to add more fields.

HTML

```
<div class="faculty_row">
    <select name="search_category"  id="search_category_id">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM t_category ORDER BY category_name ASC";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category_name'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="message[]">
</div>

<a href="#" id="add_more">Add More</a>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#add_more").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default the event
    var clone = $(".faculty_row").eq(0).clone(); // clone only first item
    $("#faculty_wrapper").append(clone); // append it to our form
});
```

Then I have jQuery Populate Second Combobox based on First Combobox

html

```
<select name="search_category"  id="search_category_id">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM t_category ORDER BY category_name ASC";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category_name'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>
</select>

<span id="show_sub_categories" align="center">
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#loader').hide();
$('#show_heading').hide();

$('#search_category_id').change(function(){
    $('#show_sub_categories').fadeOut();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post("get_chid_categories.php", {
        parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
    }, function(response){

        setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
    });
    return false;
});

function finishAjax(id, response){
$('#loader').hide();
$('#show_heading').show();
$('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
$('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id()
{
    if($('#sub_category_id').val() == '')
    alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
    alert($('#sub_category_id').val());
    return false;
}
```

Each function is run perfectly. How can I combine that 2 function to be 1? So the populate Second Combobox based on First Combobox can be run on next row if I click button Add More.

Comment: Please stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; consider to use MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, can you make a JSFiddle for your codes?

Comment: OK Thank you for your information. Please try the demo here: http://175.111.116.69/apps/test

Comment: In Stack Overflow, we prefer to test on public testing platform, such as JSFiddle.

Comment: It's hard because my code integrate with mysql data.